# I want to use turborepo in a project where I don't want to use TypeScript is this possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monorepo, micro-frontend, turborepo

I searched and read the docs but couldn't find the exact solution I also search for template and boilerplate.

How to use turborepo without using typescript any comments about it guys?

I don't want to use typescript because it's complicated for beginner when the project scale.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Looking to do something simliar.